# Ionic Camera Plugin for IOS

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

This is an issue that gets asked a lot, but none of the solutions I tried so far worked.

I am running my Ionic app on my IOS device, the coding for the camera plugin returns undefined values and stops before the options varaible as follows:

**Controller.js**

```
         $scope.picture = function($cordovaCamera, data)
         {
             $scope.Issue1 = data + "1"; // Returns Undefined1
           document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {
               $scope.Issue2 = data + "2";// Returns Undefined2 
     var options = {
           quality: 50,
           destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
           sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
           allowEdit: true,
           encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
           targetWidth: 100,
           targetHeight: 100,
           popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
           saveToPhotoAlbum: false,
           correctOrientation:true
           };
            $scope.Issue = data3 + "3"; //returns nothing
             $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageData) {
                 $scope.Issue4 = data + "4"; //returns nothing               
var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
               image.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
             }, function(err) {
                 $scope.Issue5 = err + data + "5"; //returns nothing             }); 

           }, false);
          }
```

**html page**

```
<div class="padding"><p>1: {{Issue1}}</p></div>
<div class="padding"><p>2: {{Issue2}}</p></div>
<div class="padding"><p>3: {{Issue3}}</p></div>
<div class="padding"><p>4: {{Issue4}}</p></div>
<div class="padding"><p>5: {{Issue5}}</p></div>
<div class="padding">
     <button type="button" class="button button-block button-positive" ng-disabled="commentForm.$invalid" 
     ng-click="picture(); ">
     Camera
     </button>
   </div>
```

Any Ideas on fixing this?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't register the `deviceready` eventlistener inside the function. You only need to do this, when you immediately want to execute a cordova plugin function after the device is ready. Since your `picture()` function is called by clicking a button, you need to make sure that the device is ready before you can call the function, but you shouldn't create a new event listener every time you click a button.
So event listener outside of function:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {
  var options = {
       quality: 50,
       destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
       sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
       allowEdit: true,
       encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
       targetWidth: 100,
       targetHeight: 100,
       popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
       saveToPhotoAlbum: false,
       correctOrientation:true
       };

  $scope.picture = function() { 
    $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageData) {              
      var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
      image.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
    }, function(err) {
      $scope.Issue5 = err + data + "5";
    });
  } 

}, false);
```

Comment: Did not know that thanks! But I have found a solution for my issue. :)